# Performing JOIN on more than 1 column oracle query

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, oracle9i

I have 2 tables, the first one is **MASTER_TABLE** with fields **ID, STATUS_CODE, STATUS_SUBCODE, SUBJECT_CODE, SUBJECT_SUBCODE** and the second table is **CODE_TABLE** which has the unique description for every combination of a code and subcode. It has the following  fields **CODE**, **SUBCODE** and **DESCRIPTION**

How to write a query to retrieve the **ID, STATUS** and **SUBJECT** , for example for every combination of STATUS_CODE and STATUS_SUBCODE in MASTER_TABLE I have to get the STATUS value in CODE_TABLE, similarly I have to do the same thing for SUBJECT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must join *twice* to `CODE_TABLE` - once for each type of look-up, so to distinguish the rows from eachother, you must alias at least one (but usually one would alias both, as below):

```
select 
  mt.ID,
  ct1.DESCRIPTION as STATUS
  ct2.DESCRIPTION as SUBJECT
from MASTER_TABLE mt
left join CODE_TABLE ct1 
    on ct1.CODE = mt.STATUS_CODE and ct1.SUBCODE = mt.STATUS_SUBCODE
left join CODE_TABLE ct2
    on ct2.CODE = mt.SUBJECT_CODE and ct2.SUBCODE = mt.SUBJECT_SUBCODE
```

I have made the joins `left` joins in case data is missing from `CODE_TABLE`, in which case this query would produce a `null` for the corresponding description.